# Ignite : Evict data from Cache and store into Database

Tags: ignite

I want to evict data from cache for every minute, and store it into a third-party database.

I know about write though orations.

Is there any way to write a data into a third-party database by using an eviction policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is implemented code per @Dmitriy suggestion for catching the events on cache eviction:

```
import org.apache.ignite.Ignite;
import org.apache.ignite.IgniteCache;
import org.apache.ignite.IgniteException;
import org.apache.ignite.Ignition;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.CacheMode;
import org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration;
import org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration;
import org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi;
import org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder;

import javax.cache.configuration.Factory;
import javax.cache.configuration.MutableCacheEntryListenerConfiguration;
import javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy;
import javax.cache.expiry.Duration;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class CacheEvictExample {

    private static final String CACHE_NAME = CacheEvictExample.class.getSimpleName();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IgniteException, InterruptedException {
        final IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
        cfg.setIgniteInstanceName("ignite-" + IgniteMain.class.getSimpleName());
        TcpDiscoverySpi discovery = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
        TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder();
        ipFinder.setAddresses(Arrays.asList("127.0.0.1:47500..47509"));
        discovery.setIpFinder(ipFinder);
        cfg.setDiscoverySpi(discovery);
        try (Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(cfg)) {
            System.out.println(">>> Cache events example started.");
            CacheConfiguration<Long, Person> personCacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<>(CACHE_NAME);
            personCacheCfg.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED); // Default.
            personCacheCfg.setIndexedTypes(Long.class, Person.class);
            Factory expiryPolicyFactory = CreatedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(new Duration(TimeUnit.SECONDS, 10));
            personCacheCfg.setExpiryPolicyFactory(expiryPolicyFactory);

            try (IgniteCache<Long, Person> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(personCacheCfg)) {
                cache.registerCacheEntryListener(
                        new MutableCacheEntryListenerConfiguration<>
                          (
                            () -> new CacheEntryListenerHandler(),
                            () -> new CacheEntryEventFilterHandler(),
                           true, true
                          ));

              cache.put(Long.valueOf(0), new Person(Long.valueOf(0), "Pappu", "Pyare", 2000, "Pappu Pass Ho Gaya"));
              cache.put(Long.valueOf(1), new Person(Long.valueOf(1), "Pappu", "Pyare", 2000, "Pappu Dubara Pass Ho Gaya"));

                //Wait for 11 seconds by the time cache will be expired
                Thread.sleep(11000);
                System.out.println("11 Seconds are Over. Pappu beta ooth ja!!! ---- Expired Event should trigger now");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } finally {
                ignite.destroyCache(CACHE_NAME);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Listener**

```
import javax.cache.event.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class CacheEntryListenerHandler<K, V>
        implements CacheEntryExpiredListener<K, V>, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void onExpired(Iterable<CacheEntryEvent<? extends K, ? extends V>> events) throws CacheEntryListenerException {
        for (CacheEntryEvent<? extends K, ? extends V> event : events) {
            System.out.println("Received a " + event);
            /** Persist in third party database*/
        }
    }

}
```

**EventFilter**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.cache.event.CacheEntryEvent;
import javax.cache.event.CacheEntryEventFilter;
import javax.cache.event.CacheEntryListenerException;
import javax.cache.event.EventType;

public class CacheEntryEventFilterHandler<K, V> implements CacheEntryEventFilter<K, V>, Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    final List<EventType> VALID_EVENTS = Arrays.asList(EventType.REMOVED, EventType.EXPIRED, EventType.CREATED);

    public boolean evaluate(CacheEntryEvent<? extends K, ? extends V> event)
            throws CacheEntryListenerException {
        boolean result = false;
        if (VALID_EVENTS.contains(event.getEventType())) {
            System.out.println("filter event=" + event + " filter result=" + result);
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**Model Class:**

```
import org.apache.ignite.cache.query.annotations.QuerySqlField;
import org.apache.ignite.cache.query.annotations.QueryTextField;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 * Person class.
 */

    public class Person implements Serializable {

        @QuerySqlField(index = true)
        public Long id;


        @QuerySqlField
        public String firstName;

        @QuerySqlField
        public String lastName;

        @QueryTextField
        public String resume;

        @QuerySqlField(index = true)
        public double salary;


        public Person() {

        }

        public Person(Long id, String firstName, String lastName, double salary, String resume) {
            this.id = id;
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.salary = salary;
            this.resume = resume;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person [id=" + id +
                    ", lastName=" + lastName +
                    ", firstName=" + firstName +
                    ", salary=" + salary +
                    ", resume=" + resume + ']';
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for answer,can you share any simple example which only use eviction policy and then write into database. when i write eviction policy is this call to any of the method from write through or read through property?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set expiration policy to 1 minute and listen to expiring events. You can persist to 3rd party database directly from the listener.

Here are some examples:

https://coderecipesblog.wordpress.com/2016/11/20/jcache-expiry-policy-example/

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/coherence/develop-applications/jcache_events.htm#COHDG5823